# MYSQL draw Distinct Record of 2 Column

Tags: mysql, sql

MYSQL draw Distinct Record of 2 Column

I have this 3 column

```
group_id
group_name
group_account_id


Example 3 records

group_id = 1
group_name = N.A
group_account_id = 2001


group_id = 2
group_name = Magic
group_account_id = 2001

group_id = 3
group_name = N.A
group_account_id = 2002
```

Initially I draw record by this way

```
select DISTINCT group_name from groupTBL;
```

But the above line only get me N.A and Magic, as there are 2 group as N.A but they are of different account_id.

I want to draw out the 3 records, DISTINCT group_name, but distinct does not apply to different account_id.

The result should be

```
N.A
Magic
N.A
```

Means

If there are 1 more additional record

```
group_id = 4
group_name = N.A
group_account_id = 2002
```

The result will still be 3, as group_id 3 have the same group name and group_account_id as group_id 4

The result should still be

```
N.A
Magic
N.A
```

**Thanks for helping**

Answer (score 4):

You can use `GROUP BY` for this:

```
select group_name
from groups 
group by group_name, group_account_id
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59610/1)